# Configuring kismet Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: ubuntu, installation, ubuntu-18.04, kismet-udk

I have the following error when the system is 'setting-up' kismet..

```
The provided user list contains invalid usernames.The users to be added 
to the kismet group have to be provided in a space-separated list of 
usernames. It seems that the following usernames are not valid: 
userOne. Please revise the list.
```

Moreover, any installation/removal process is now stuck at this where I can only enter 'ok' but then I am back at the error message.

How do I solve this? I thought I could find a list with users but it is not the case, I don't know where it is taking this userOne username.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply solved by

```
sudo dpkg --remove kismet
```

Comment: I have the same problem. I removed (purged) kismet but can't install it again. When I try to install it I get the same prompt...

Answer (score 1):

The only thing you need to do is to add a single user called "root" and you will proceed to the next options I actually came here to seek an answer but none of what was provided above worked out for me so I had to figure it out myself

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

The error means that the user account indicated was deleted therefore you are required to add the user account again and make sure the account type is as it was eg.administrator and go ahead and click ok.